# Javascript function at global scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-maps

I'm trying to load the google maps js api on a wordpress site, and I just keep getting an "initMap is not a function" error. I figure I probably am writing my code wrong, I adapted it from a standalone page, so perhaps working it in to wordpress messed things up. I was having an issue with the JS files not loading in the correct order, but now my JS loads before Google Maps, so that wouldn't be the issue. It must be something wrong with the initMap function. This is the function that is causing the error. I thought I had passed it to a global scope, but I'm not sure I did it correctly.

Api key call

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'google-maps-js', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=###key###&callback=initMap', array(), '20151215', true );
```

Function in the js file

```
jQuery(function($) {
    window.initMap = function() {

        // Disallow drag on mobile
        var isDraggable = $(document).width() > 480 ? true : false;

      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        scrollwheel: false,
        draggable: isDraggable,
        streetViewControl: false,
        styles: [{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"labels.text","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#444444"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#f2f2f2"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":45}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#1764c0"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#1764c0"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#2fa000"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#2fa000"},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#2fa000"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#2fa000"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#46bcec"},{"visibility":"on"}]}]
      });

      // Center map in between California LatLng(36.778261, -119.417932) and New York LatLng(40.712784, -74.005941)
      map.fitBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(36.778261, -119.417932), new google.maps.LatLng(40.712784, -74.005941)))
    };
});
```

Comment: There is no `initMaps` function - you have an `initMap` - singular. Also, that's not being called anywhere, nor is `initMaps` (plural) being called. At least in the code shown.

Comment: Sorry, I meant initMap. InitMaps is not a function anywhere! The error is for initMap.

Comment: dont show your key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try move you initMap function outside the jquery init

```
<script>
    function initMap() {

        // Disallow drag on mobile
        var isDraggable = $(document).width() > 480 ? true : false;

      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        scrollwheel: false,
        draggable: isDraggable,
        streetViewControl: false,
        styles: [{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"labels.text","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#444444"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#f2f2f2"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":45}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#1764c0"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#1764c0"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#2fa000"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#2fa000"},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#2fa000"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#2fa000"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#46bcec"},{"visibility":"on"}]}]
      });

      // Center map in between California LatLng(36.778261, -119.417932) and New York LatLng(40.712784, -74.005941)
      map.fitBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(36.778261, -119.417932), new google.maps.LatLng(40.712784, -74.005941)))
    };

</script>
```

Comment: That did it! Dang it, I made it global to try and fix the error and apparently I just made it worse. Thanks!

Comment: probably a timing issue. You tried calling initmap before jquery was done loading.

Comment: if you put the function of those that must be created when the whole document was created (as you did) the Google Maps does not find the callback function .. but if you declare in the scope of the script then the function is created before load the entire document